# How to format date time object with format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: c++, boost, date

How could I print the current date, using [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) libraries, in the format dd/mm/yyyy H?

What I have:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(now).c_str();

2009-Dec-14 23:31:40
```

But I want:

> 14-Dec-2009 23:31:40

Answer (score 81):

If you're using [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/date_time.html), this is done using IO facets.

You need to include `boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp` to get the correct facet typedefs (`wtime_facet`, `time_facet`, etc.) for `boost::posix_time::ptime`.  Once this is done, the code is pretty simple.  You call imbue on the `ostream` you want to output to, then just output your `ptime`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  time_facet *facet = new time_facet("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S");
  cout.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), facet));
  cout << second_clock::local_time() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
14-Dec-2009 16:13:14
```

See also the [list of format flags](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags) in the boost docs, in case you want to output something fancier.

Comment: And http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags for the format flags.

Comment: @Jules cout will take ownership. See http://rhubbarb.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/boost-datetime-locales-and-facets/

Comment: The locale takes the ownership. So if you keep this locale stored you can use it any output stream, not just cout

Comment: Funny side-node: drove me almost nuts that I could not get it running correctly when trying to get formated date time into std::wstring. I finally realized there is a boost::posix_time::wtime_facet.

Comment: WARNING: don't put time_facet *facet = new time_facet("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"); in a boost::shared_ptr!!!! you will spend your next day debugging the crazy crash.

Answer (score 1):

With the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) you can print the date in the required format as follows:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <fmt/time.h>

int main() {
  auto now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
  fmt::print("{:%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S}\n", to_tm(now));
}
```

This formatting facility is being proposed for standardization in C++20: [P0645](http://wg21.link/p0645).

Alternatively you can use [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) which was introduced in C++11:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
  auto tm = to_tm(now);
  std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S");
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.