# Convert boost::posix_time::ptime to string using custom time zone

Tags: c++, boost, timezone

I have a `boost::posix_time::ptime` instance and would like to convert ("format") it to a string using a given `boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr` instance. Below is a test program showing what I currently have. It converts a `ptime` to a `local_date_time` which, from my understanding, expresses a time zone in addition to the time information.

When running this program at 2011-08-18 12:00:00 UTC, I expect the output `2011-08-18 14.00.00 UTC+02:00`. Instead it prints `2011-08-18 12:00:00 UTC+00:00`. i.e. Relative to the printed time zone, the printed time is correct, but it's not in the time zone I used to create the `boost::local_time::local_date_time` instance.

I currently use the technique suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018188/how-to-format-a-datetime-to-string-using-boost) to use a custom format string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    using namespace std;

    // Get current time, as an example
    boost::posix_time::ptime dt = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    // Create a time_zone_ptr for the desired time zone and use it to create a local_date_time
    boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr zone(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("EST"));
    boost::local_time::local_date_time dt_with_zone(dt, zone);

    std::stringstream strm;

    // Set the formatting facet on the stringstream and print the local_date_time to it.
    // Ownership of the boost::local_time::local_time_facet object goes to the created std::locale object.
    strm.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC%Q")));
    strm << dt_with_zone;

    // Print the stream's content to the console
    cout << strm.str() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How should I convert the `local_date_time` instance to a string so the date in the string is represented using the time zone specified by the `time_zone_ptr` instance?

Comment: Thanks, Emile, I added a specific question at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think boost does not know the time zone specifier. Replace

```
new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("EST")
```

in your code by

```
new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("EST-05:00:00")
```

and everything works fine. If you want to use the common standard names, you have to create a timezone database as described in the boost documentation.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! As the constructor does not throw an exception when confronted with an unknown time zone specification, I was not thinking about that being the case.