# how to return std::string from a function in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to return a string from a function that does some processing.

I've tried returning it as an rvalue reference and also as an lvalue reference. didn't work :(.

processing function:

```
std::string processingFunction()
{
    std::string str = "";
    //processing...
    strftime(&str[0], MAX_LENGTH, DATE_FORMAT, tm_STRUCT_ADRRESS);
    return str;
}
```

use of the function:

```
std::string temp = processingFunction();
if(temp.empty())
{
    //stuff
}
```

When debugging (in VS 2019), I can see the value of `temp` in the Watch, but `temp.empty()` always returns `1`. Even if I can see that the value is present.

here is a screenshot for tl;dr:
[m_bucket_function is the processing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otHKB.png)

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Comment: temp.empty() tests if the string is empty and a value of 0 means false so that means the string is not empty.  But you were expecting it to be non-empty weren't you?  So I think that means it is working.

Comment: Use `if (!temp.empty())`.

Comment: Yes, because you said it yourself - temp is not empty ("I can see the value") https://repl.it/repls/OddDarkgrayProcess

Comment: sorry people, I got confused. 'str.empty()' always returns '1'!

Comment: Can you show what's in your "//processing" code? Maybe you just did not do anything with the string returned, hence always returning an empty string?

Comment: I'll edit some in.

Comment: You're writing into the `str` buffer without resizing it first to be able to hold that data. Big no, UB.

Comment: Well, there is your problem. C++ string is not a simple `char*`. You have size information, etc. in it, which will not be written in this case. `strftime` does not work with strings. It works with `char*` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You define a `std::string` object and set it to `""` (the empty string).

You then use `strftime()` to copy, as a C-style string, a representation of some time to memory starting at `&str[0]`.

The expression `&str[0]` (where `str` is a `std::string`) does give you access to the initial byte of the data managed by the `str::string` object -- but it doesn't allocate memory to hold the new value, and it doesn't update the `std::string` object's internal data (including the length of the string it represents). Your call to `strftime()` is likely to clobber unallocated memory (undefined behavior).

You need to use `strftime()` to copy data into a `char` array, and then copy that data into your `str`. `std::string`'s assignment operator will then take care of updating the metadata and allocating memory as needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with returning a `std::string` by value, as you're doing.

> temp.empty() always returns 1

just means the string is empty.

Now that you've posted more code and as @SkyZip comments, the problem lies in:

```
strftime(&str[0], ...
```

this gets `strftime` to **overwrite memory** by passing it the address of your string.

Comment: but it's not empty, I can see its content.

Comment: Try printing `temp` and `temp.empty()` after the function returns. Either it'll be empty or not.

Comment: It's not empty because strftime writes in it! It WILL modify the string's 'value' but not its size information nor anything else. Hence your empty string.

Comment: You are welcome, but see the other's answer's. They explained the problem very well. I posted a solution which might work in your case, but maybe you should look for a more 'c++' style solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use strftime you can do it like so:

```
std::string processingFunction()
{
    char buff[MAX_LENGTH];
    strftime(buff, MAX_LENGTH, DATE_FORMAT, tm_STRUCT_ADRRESS);
    //processing...
    return std::string(buff);
}
```

And as @Keith said, you are working with objects here. Not just plain old C data types.

**Edit:**
Just for reference, here is a similar question:
[Current date and time as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357999/current-date-and-time-as-string)

Comment: `return std::string(buff);` could simply be `return buff;` since the return value will be converted to `std::string` anyway.

Comment: Yes, it could be. But to my understanding, that would be an implicit way to call the constructor, and most of the time, I'd rather use the explicit way. With conversions, too.

Comment: I hate to be picky (disclaimer: I **love** to be picky), but C++'s meaning for the word "object" is not related to object-oriented programming. For example, given `int foo = 42;`, `foo` is an object.

Comment: Sorry, my English vocabulary still needs to improve in this regard. What choice of words do you suggest to make my point more clear?