# What is the difference between boost::posix_time::time_facet and boost::gregorian::date_facet?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, gregorian-calendar

Different answers to [this question about formatting date + time strings using Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018188/how-to-format-a-datetime-to-string-using-boost) use different facets.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020490/368896) uses `boost::posix_time::time_facet`, and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265390/368896) uses `boost::gregorian::date_facet` (note that the latter also includes the **time**, despite the name of the facet class).

I.e., we have:

```
boost::posix_time::time_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

vs.

```
boost::gregorian::date_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

(with irrelevant characters slightly adjusted by me from the linked answers).

Notice, again, that the `boost::gregorian::date_facet` includes the **time**, so in a sense calling it a `date_facet` is a bit deceptive, especially when contrasting it with `boost::posix_time::time_facet`, whose developers clearly felt should include "time" in the name of the facet class.

Also notice that `boost::posix_time::time_facet` includes the **date**, which is perhaps more intuitive (though it is possible to think of purely formatting *times*, but not *dates*, so maybe it shouldn't be more intuitive that a "time" facet can include the "date" than that a "date" facet can include the "time").

But back specifically to my question: I feel that somehow I must be missing something important involving the `gregorian` aspect of things if I use the `boost::posix_time` version - people wouldn't bother making a namespace to represent the *Gregorian* calendar if that doesn't matter, right?

And conversely - is `boost::gregorian`'s version missing something important from the `boost::posix_time` version?

Is one of them a superset of the other?  Alternatively, do their features overlap, but differ?

**What is the difference between `boost::posix_time::time_facet` and `boost::gregorian::date_facet`?**

Comment: Posix time starts in 1970. Gregorian calendar starts in 1572 (and the facet supports dates earlier than that).

Comment: Thanks.  Does Posix also support dates prior to 1970 (via negative values)?  I assume it does.

Comment: I looked in the documentation after typing the comment. Apparently posix_time::time_facet extends gregorian::date_facet.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Those two are typedefs. ([1](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/6015e3039114c0f2ba456e00dd50404e3fb88275/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp#L32) [2](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/6015e3039114c0f2ba456e00dd50404e3fb88275/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp#L38) ). So it's really `boost::date_time::date_facet` and `boost::date_time::time_facet`. [Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) says: "The boost::date_time::time_facet is an extension of the boost::date_time::date_facet."