# How to achieve this specific datetime format using boost?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, formatting

I want to format a datetime like this:

**YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS**

eg, 4 digit year, followed by 2 digit **months**, followed by 2 digit day, underscore, 24-hour hour, 2 digit **minutes**, 2 digit seconds.

e.g.: 16th of February 2011, 8:05 am and 2 seconds would be:

**20110216_080502**

What format string should I use in the following code to achieve this? (And, if necessary, what code changes are needed):

```
//...#includes, namespace usings...

ptime now = second_clock::universal_time();

wstringstream ss;
time_facet *facet = new time_facet("???"); //what goes here?
ss.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), facet));
ss << now;

wstring datetimestring = ss.str();
```

Here are some strings I've tried so far:

**%Y%m%d_%H%M%S** : "2011-Feb-16 16:51:16"

**%Y%m%d** : "2011-Feb-16"

**%H%M%S** : "16:51:16"

Here's another one:

**%Y** : "2011-Feb-16 16:51:16" *huh??*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904317/c-boost-date-with-format-dd-mm-yyyy/1904368#1904368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use `wtime_facet`, not `time_facet`. See the [working program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018188/how-to-format-a-datetime-to-string-using-boost/5020490#5020490) I posted on your other question.

Answer (score 1):

From [date/time facet format flags](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags):

```
"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  time_facet *facet = new time_facet("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S");
```

Comment: Weirdly, this is the exact string I came up with too, but it doesn't format correctly for me - you get colons between hours minutes and seconds, and months are a three-letter abbreviation.