# Boost ptime: how to format data in a way browsers send inside headers of http requests?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I need to format my ptime in such way `Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT` How to do such thing with boost? (so it would look like data format of HTTP servers `Expires` and `Last-Modified` and `Date` response headers )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904317/c-boost-date-with-format-dd-mm-yyyy<br/> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786201/parsing-of-date-time-from-string-boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

std::string current_time_formatted()
{
    namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;

    static char const* const fmt = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    // assumes std::cout's locale has been set appropriately for the entire app
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new bpt::time_facet(fmt)));
    ss << bpt::second_clock::universal_time();
    return ss.str();
}
```

See [Date Time Input/Output](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) for more information on the available format flags.