# How to format date and time string in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, mfc

Let's say I have time_t and tm structure. I can't use Boost but MFC. How can I make it a string like following?

```
Mon Apr 23 17:48:14 2012
```

Is using sprintf the only way?

Comment: [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/libs/date_time) has formatted I/O facilities.

Comment: With a sentence or two more, that could be a (the?) answer, @ildjarn

Comment: @Jasper : While I use the library, I find recommending it to other people difficult because the documentation is so horrible. I just left a comment so the OP could pursue that on their own if they choose (e.g. there are plenty of SO answers demonstrating exactly this, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5697577/636019)).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The C library includes [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) specifically for formatting dates/times. The format you're asking for seems to correspond to something like this:

```
char buffer[256];

strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &your_tm);
```

I believe [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) uses a similar format string, though it does relieve you of having to explicitly deal with a buffer. If you want to write the output to a stream, it's quite convenient, but to get it into a string it's not a lot of help -- you'd have to do something like:

```
std::stringstream buffer;

buffer << std::put_time(&your_tm, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");

// now the result is in `buffer.str()`.
```

`std::put_time` is new with C++11, but C++03 has a `time_put` facet in a locale that *can* do the same thing. If memory serves, I did manage to make it work once, but after that decided it wasn't worth the trouble, and I haven't done it since.

Comment: Just wanted to note gcc still lacks support for put_time :/

Comment: It's done on GCC 5. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137287/4123703

Answer (score 17):

I'd try `std::put_time`.  See the [link here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) for information on how to use it.  It supports full format strings and such.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is C++11-only.

Comment: Still not implemented yet (gcc 4.8.1).

Answer (score 2):

`ctime()` produces strings in that format. It takes a pointer to a `time_t`.
There's also `asctime()` that takes a pointer to a `struct tm` and does the same.

Comment: `ctime(&curtime)`, where time_t curtime; reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ctime.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you need to worry about formatting on different locales, don't forget to initialize the CRT with the current locale.
This affects COleDateTime too.

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE,“.OCP”); // sets the sort order

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, “.OCP”); // sets the currency formatting rules

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, “.OCP”); // sets the formatting of numerals

setlocale(LC_TIME, “.OCP”); // defines the date/time formatting
```

See my blog post which ties in MSDN articles and other sources. 
http://gilesey.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/initailizing-mfccrt-for-consumption-of-regional-settings-internationalizationc

Answer (score 1):

MFC has [`COleDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx) which has a contructor that takes `time_t` (or `__time64_t`) and has a [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bab3feb1.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
CTime obj1(time_tObj);

CString s = obj1.Format( "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" );
```