# How to get date in a particular format

Tags: c

I have been searching on the net on how to get and store the current date in `yyyymmdd` format. There are many code out there but it formats the dos `%date%:%time%` output to required specs.

The problem with that is, I need it to work universally across all regional settings. I can't find the code example to do that.

Can anyone help? If this is not possible, then is there a way to change the regional setting temporarily write the file and change it back to what it was?

Comment: Dating is a particularly difficult topic for your stereotypical developer ;)

Comment: It is not a dup q. And the previous question has no relation to what I am asking. I guess dating is a problem here ;)

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289017/how-to-format-date-and-time-string-in-c) and its accepted answer. The title says C++, but the answer uses a C library. I think it might help you