# c++ modify char inside function

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I created a function to retrieve date from a esp32 using c++. Buts it's causing a error.

I see dozens of sites and none of solutions worked to me. The code can change to a better practice if you provide it.

the ideia is. 
create a function to return a DateTime in a char.

```
void getCurrentDateTime(char **datetime){
  time_t tt = time(NULL);
  data = *gmtime(&tt);
  strftime(datetime, 64, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &data);
}
```

I call that function this way.

```
char *datetime; 
getCurrentDateTime(&datetime);  // my function
```

The code compiles but crash the esp32 device...

I'm in very beginning of c++ code... so i appreciate if you explain and provide a code for function and a how to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize the `dateTime` pointer.there is no allocated memory where `datetime` pointer points to. so when `strftime` trying to fill it, it crashes.
initialize it with some predefined size of memory

```
char *datetime = new char(80); 
getCurrentDateTime(&datetime);
```

update:
also `strftime` takes a `char*` as first parameter , but you are passing `char**`

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `datetime` first, and pass it as `char*` to the function.

```
#include <ctime>

void getCurrentDateTime(char* datetime){
    time_t tt = time(NULL);
    tm data = *gmtime(&tt);
    strftime(datetime, 64, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &data);
}

int main() {
    char datetime[64];
    getCurrentDateTime(datetime);
}
```

Comment: thanks. that's worked. Just for learning purpose, if i don't know the length of the char... can i instance other char inside function with other length?

Comment: @EricTorres With `strftime()`, you must select some length yourself. But you can use `std::put_time()` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289017/how-to-format-date-and-time-string-in-c

Answer (score -1):

```
strftime(*datetime, 64, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &data);
```

Without further testing Id say its because you need to dereference your "reference-pointer".

Your datetime comes in as 'pointer to a char[]' and then youre trying to print to the pointer instead of the char[]